# Why doesn't my code work? Please look and see if you can help me

Tags: python-3.x

Assuming that the population of a country A is of the order of 80 000 inhabitants with a rate 
annual growth of 3% and the population B  is the population of 20 0000 inhabitants at a rate of growthprogram to calculate and write the number of years required 
for the population of country A exceeds or equals the population of country B, kept rates 
growth.

After do this I need to do another program for to change the previous program allowing the user to inform the population and growth rates initials. Validate input and allow repeat operation.

I did this form but doesn't work ...

[here](http://ideone.com/AuYpoi)

```
years = int(input("anecesary years: "))

populA = 80000
populB = 200000

years = 0

growthA = 0.03
growthB = 0.015 

while populA > populB:
    years += 1

populA = populA + (populA * growthA)
populB = populB + (populB * growthB)
print("after %i years the country  A exceeded the country B :",years)
print("P A: ", populA)
print("P B: " ,populB)
```

Comment: Why do you say it's a SyntaxError in the title?

Comment: Sorry ... I thinked was the syntax error

Answer (score 2):

```
populA = 80000
populB = 200000
```

`while populA > populB:`

There is your problem, your code will not run as `populA` is **less than** `populB` starting off not  greater than `>`.

Change to:

```
while populA < populB:
```

You also reset `years` to `0` after your `years = int(input("anecesary years: "))` when you use `years = 0` which I doubt is what you want.

So your code should look something like the following, `remove years = 0` and make sure `populA = populA + (populA * growthA) etc..` is inside the while loop:

```
years = int(input("anecesary years: "))

populA = 80000
populB = 200000   

growthA = 0.03
growthB = 0.015

while populA < populB:
    years += 1
    populA += populA * growthA # same as populA = populA + (populA * growthA)
    populB += populB * growthB
print("after %i years the country  A exceeded the country B :", years)
print("P A: ", populA)
print("P B: ", populB)
```

Comment: Hi Mrº Padraic, thank's for answer , I almost hit the exercise, only there (in the while) I got lost ... really thank's, and about the other question,for to change the previous program allowing the user to inform the population and growth rates initials. Validate input and allow repeat operation, I can use this program again right? I need to creat a new ...?

Comment: @Susan, if I understand you correctly then yes you can reuse it no problem,  you should just make it a function and you can  call it when needed.

Comment: Hum, so I don't need to create a new, ok ... but create a function ... ãh ... I need to put below the last line print("P B: ", populB)  new int(input( the function name )) ... right... ?? ...(I believe is wrong ... sorry)

Comment: Hi, thank's for help me, I only didn't understand the function part XD

Comment: @Susan, to create a function, you just def my_function() and put all the code inside, then just call it using my_function()

Comment: Ok, so I only need to put  the  def years() in the first line,on the top years and in the last line years(), right? Sorry for this ... I don't quite understand the concept of functions well.